Why does copy_rates_range() return only 1 or 0 bar most of the time in MetaTrader5?
I am using MetaTrader 5 for python and regardless of the specified range, symbol and timeframe, copy_rates_range() almost always returns 0 or 1 bars. In the docs they say it's normal for the first call and that the requested data will be ready for subsequent calls but it just never is.

It would be helpful for answering your question if you exposed your relevant code and the returned data.
